# Change the display name of Title field in "All Items" View using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

Using Powershell script i have change the Display name of **Title** column to **New Request** in Content Type.

I have use that content type in **Custom list**. 
When click on new item in list it will display **New Request** instead of  **Title**.

But in default **All items** view it still display **Title**.

Is that possible to change All items view field **"Title"** display name?

Comment: You can use use SharePoint's Client Side Rendering Framework for changing the display name

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this [blog](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/) to understand how to apply CSR.

The code which you can write to modify column names is as below (I am currently modifying "Title"):

```
(function () {


    function preTaskFormRenderer(renderCtx) {
       modifyColumns(renderCtx);       
    }


    function modifyColumns(renderCtx)
    {
      var arrayLength= renderCtx.ListSchema.Field.length;
        for (var i=0; i < arrayLength;i++)
        {
           if(renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i].DisplayName == 'order_number')
             {
               var newTitle= "New Title";
               var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[i];
               linkTitleField.DisplayName = newTitle;
             }
         }
    }

    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var ctxForm = {};
      ctxForm.Templates = {};
      ctxForm.OnPreRender = preTaskFormRenderer;
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

You can also for loop to find position of a particular field. `var linkTitleField = renderCtx.ListSchema.Field[0];` Here "0" refers to the position of the field. As i mentioned above you can iterate over the fields to find the position of the desired column.